# typeof class or any of its subclasses instead of instance of class

Tags: typescript

I have these classes

```
class Foo {}

class A extends Foo {}

class B extends Foo {}
```

now I want to make an interface that has property `type` that its type is class not instance of class

```
interface Bar {
    type  : XXXX;     // I don't know to put here
    value : string;
}
```

so I can create an instance of that interface like this

```
const x : Bar = {
    type  : Foo, // or and of its subclasses for example A or B
    value : 'test',
}
```

I don't want instance of `Foo` but a class of `Foo` that

```
{
    type : new Foo(),
    value : "test"
}
```

should not be valid

I hope I explained my problem correctly

Comment: Do generics suit for you?

Comment: Ok not problem, but how generics could solve my problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you just want a [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) of the form `new () => Foo`, meaning "a constructor of zero arguments that produces an instance of type `Foo`".  Like this:

```
interface Bar {
     type: new () => Foo;
     value: string;
}

const x: Bar = {
     type: Foo,
     value: 'test',
};
const y: Bar = {
     type: A,
     value: ""
};
const z: Bar = {
     type: new Foo(), // error!
//   ~~~~ <-- // Type 'Foo' is not assignable to type 'new () => Foo'.
     value: ""
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.2#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8CwAoaWtmgXmgEYMBfDDUSGAQWgFMAPAFzoDsATGBJNTbaAEb5oAJlLl0lKNABC9Zm05xEKDP2jBhAZnHoMAS1YsATgDMwwOrLDHVfbEwCeABzoAuaKzoB3aAAoASnwAPmV4AG41fgA3MBAAV3doCCZjQwBzSPQyPUl4VhToBg8ZG2FedSdXD24AGijsWISkgHIWFJb67KzgfMLHErKCCv4qpOou9SbEjwAiWdIevqZoAC9B22GGrDGPL19uQNroAHoT+mNjeGMAQm3T86wAPxen6AAeAFpPh+gAFRcVha3Ba0H0MFY8BWVH06VYYAEICsTCQY2gLX2-iCeFCIIAdPdpkl5rogA)

Comment: `typeof Foo` wil also work instead of `new () => Foo`.